# Looking for cleaner declarative way to reduce nesting with spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I don't like using map and looping to create a new array from an old array in JavaScript when just one item changes.  I have a simple array that has data like this:

```
const speakerData = [{name: 'joe',id: 101,favorite: true},
                     {name: 'sam',id: 102,favorite: false},
                     {name: 'jon',id: 103,favorite: false}]
```

And I want to update record 102 to favorite is true (toggle favorite).

I have the following code that works:

```
const speakerId = 102;
const newSpeakerData = speakerData.map((rec) => {
  if (rec.id === speakerId) {
    rec.favorite = !rec.favorite;
    return rec;
  } else {
    return rec;
  }
});
```

I want something like what I have below but it obviously does not work.

```
const speakerRec = speakerData.find(a=>a.id === speakerId);
speakerRec.favorite = !speakerRec.favorite;
const newSpeakerData = [{...speakerData},speakerRec]
```

Is there a clever one line I can make this happen with ES7?

**Here is the answer** I was looking for that @adiga put in the comments below.

```
const speakerId = parseInt(e.target.attributes['data-sessionid'].value);
const index = speakerData.findIndex((a) => a.id === speakerId);
const newSpeakerData = Object.assign([...speakerData], {
  [index]: { ...speakerData[index], favorite: !speakerData[index].favorite }
});
```

Comment: Intead of `find`, use `findIndex` like: `const newSpeakerData = [...speakerData]; const index = speakerData.findIndex(a=>a.id === speakerId); newSpeakerData[index] = <immutably update index>; setState(..)`

Comment: <immutably update index> is the part I'm having trouble with

Comment: Pete your question is alright to me, and was upvoted. There are many people that doesn't understand how hard can be to communicate and reacts eagerly with downvoting. As far i can see on your questions, you need to modify an item of a collection, so using find is OK as it returns a reference to the object you need to modify, and using that reference you can modified any object's fields. But also, you need to create a brand new collection containing all the elements plus the new one modified? or i'm understanding wrong? [BTW: using a map for modifying an array's item is not a common practice]

Comment: @Victor Did you upvote to outweigh the downvote on the question, or because (hover over the upvote button) "_This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear_"? Your "_or i'm understanding wrong?_" suggests that you don't really find it crystal clear. Upvoting to balance out a downvote [is highly inappropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311408).

Comment: "_but it obviously does not work_" What doesn't work @Pete? The first two lines of what you show [seem to do exactly what you are asking for](https://jsfiddle.net/ymertaxc/).

Comment: I'm confused about why this has the 'immutability' tag on it. Are you trying to manipulate an existing object in place in the array or create a new array with new objects?

Comment: note that in your three lines code, you may fail if id is not found (which would not have occured by nesting)

Comment: I'm looking for a more language rich solution than using find or findrec. If it's not possible to use the spread operator I understand that but I've seen other examples where it seems possible using syntax similar to my suggestion of [...,newrec]. Thank you to whoever re-opened this as well as whoever upvoted. I upvote all the time and I don't believe you have to have a appropriate reason.

Comment: @Ivar, this does not work: `const newSpeakerData = [{...speakerData},speakerRec]`

Comment: "*I don't like using map and looping to create a new array from an old array*" - what exactly do you not like about it? It seems to do exactly what you want. Are you concerned about readability? Then use a helper function. Or about performance? Something else?

Comment: Notice that `rec.favorite = !rec.favorite` is not immutable.

Comment: @Bergi, my aim is to minimize nesting and if I can do it with the spread operator and parameters to that, I can minimize the nesting map introduces. this post here on SO has something similar to what I want but have not been able to morph it to my problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673783/replace-array-entry-with-spread-syntax-in-one-line-of-code

Comment: `const newSpeakerData = [...speakerData], index = speakerData.findIndex(a=> a.id === speakerId), obj = speakerData[index]; newSpeakerData[index] = { ...obj, favorite: !obj.favorite }; setState(..)`

Comment: I don't know why this is reopned. The duplicate explains how to do this without mapping over every object

Comment: @adiga, as the op here, my question never asked how to solve the problem without using .map.  That came up in the discussion. I'm still looking for a way to do this using the spread operator similar to how the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673783/replace-array-entry-with-spread-syntax-in-one-line-of-code was worked out. That is why the question was re-opened because it has not been answered yet.

Comment: `const index = speakerData.findIndex(a=> a.id === speakerId); this.setState({ speakerData: Object.assign([...speakerData], { [index]: {...speakerData[index], favorite: !speakerData[index].favorite}})})`

Comment: Thanks @adiga. That is exactly the answer I was looking for and I've updated my question to include the answer. If you want to past that code into an answer, I'll happily accept it.  Also, the syntax I still don't get is this `[index]:` but it does work.

Comment: You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45673826/3082296)

Answer (score 0):

One option is, while mapping, also put `favorite: id === speakerId ? !favorite : favorite` into the returned object:

```js
const speakerData = [{
    name: 'joe',
    id: 101,
    favorite: true
  },
  {
    name: 'sam',
    id: 102,
    favorite: false
  },
  {
    name: 'jon',
    id: 103,
    favorite: false
  }
];
const speakerId = 102;
const mappedData = speakerData.map(({ favorite, name, id }) => ({
  name,
  id,
  favorite: id === speakerId ? !favorite : favorite
}));
console.log(mappedData);
```

Doesn't look *that* pretty, but that's what I'd prefer, and I'm doubtful there's a better way.

Or, you can squish it onto one line if you really have to (but you probably shouldn't, it's too hard to read):

```
const mappedData = speakerData.map(({ favorite, name, id }) => ({ name, id, favorite: id === speakerId ? !favorite : favorite }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much need the `map` for keeping the array immutable, but you might get away with a neater syntax by using the conditional operator instead of `if`/`else` statements:

```
const speakerId = 102;
const newSpeakerData = speakerData.map((rec) =>
  rec.id === speakerId
    ? {...rec, favorite: !rec.favorite}
    : rec
);
```

(The spread syntax usage also makes sure not to mutate the `rec` object).

If this is still too long or has too much indentation, you can of course write a helper function instead to use like

```
const matchSpeakerId = rec => rec.id === 102;
const newSpeakerData = mapWhere(speakerData, matchSpeakerId, rec => ({...rec, favorite: !rec.favorite}));
```