# How to empty a text box by using a button in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a text box to input numbers, and after pressing the button, I want to clear the text box value. I have no idea how to do it, and can anybody help me?

[image: Table]

Example: When I press the add button in the Chairs row, 10 should be cleared.

```
<CRow>
  <CCol className="col-sm-6">
    <CFormInput
      id="quantity"
      type="number"
      name="quantity"
      max={item.available}
      min={1}
      onChange={(e) => {
        resetErrors()
        quantity[index] = e.target.value
      }}
    />
  </CCol>
  <CCol>
    <CButton
      color="success"
      size="sm"
      onClick={() => {
        resetErrors()
        handleSave(item._id, index)
      }}
    >
      <CIcon icon={cilPlus} className="me-2" />
      Add
    </CButton>
  </CCol>
</CRow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a state for the `quantity` and then update that state whenever the user enters a new value to that new value. Or when the `Clear` button is pressed update it to `0`.

> You could of course also update to an empty string if you want. You would then just need to be careful with the types as `+` means string concatenation if a string is involved, not addition. So make sure your program handles that correctly.

```js
function App() {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input value={quantity} type="number" onChange={e => setQuantity(e.target.valueAsNumber)} />
      <button onClick={() => setQuantity(0)}>Clear</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Also it seems you are using an array as for all quantities which is perfectly fine, just make sure that you create a new array when you update a quantity as state should be treated as immutable. Additionally, in React and re-render is only triggered when the reference of the array changes as only a shallow comparison (NOT a deep comparison) of arrays is done. You could do that e.g. like this:

> [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673783/replace-array-entry-with-spread-syntax-in-one-line-of-code) might also be helpful in that regard.

```js
// original
const quantities = [3, 12, 24];
// index to update the array on
const index = 1;
// create a new array with the quantity at index increased by 1
const newQuantities = [...quantities.slice(0, index), quantities[index] + 1, ...quantities.slice(index + 1)];

// arrays are actually two different arrays
console.log(quantities);
console.log(newQuantities);
// references are not the same
console.log(quantities === newQuantities);
```